# arrange multiple graphs using a for loop in ggplot2

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I want to produce a pdf which shows multiple graphs, one for each `NetworkTrackingPixelId`.
I have a data frame similar to this:

```
> head(data)
  NetworkTrackingPixelId                           Name       Date Impressions
1                   2421                    Rubicon RTB 2014-02-16      168801
2                   2615                     Google RTB 2014-02-16     1215235
3                   3366                      OpenX RTB 2014-02-16      104419
4                   3606                   AppNexus RTB 2014-02-16      170757
5                   3947                   Pubmatic RTB 2014-02-16       68690
6                   4299            Improve Digital RTB 2014-02-16         701
```

I was thinking to use a script similar to the one below:

```
# create a vector which stores the NetworkTrackingPixelIds
tp <- data %.%
        group_by(NetworkTrackingPixelId) %.%
        select(NetworkTrackingPixelId)

# create a for loop to print the line graphs
for (i in tp) {
      print(ggplot(data[which(data$NetworkTrackingPixelId == i), ], aes(x = Date, y = Impressions)) + geom_point() + geom_line())
    }
```

I was expecting this command to produce many graphs, one for each NetworkTrackingPixelId. Instead the result is an unique graph which aggregate all the NetworkTrackingPixelIds.

Another thing I've noticed is that the variable `tp` is not a real vector.

```
> is.vector(tp)
[1] FALSE
```

Even if I force it..

```
tp <- as.vector(data %.%
        group_by(NetworkTrackingPixelId) %.%
        select(NetworkTrackingPixelId))
> is.vector(tp)
[1] FALSE
> str(tp)
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 1397 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ NetworkTrackingPixelId: int  2421 2615 3366 3606 3947 4299 4429 4786 6046 6286 ...
 - attr(*, "vars")=List of 1
  ..$ : symbol NetworkTrackingPixelId
 - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "indices")=List of 63
  ..$ : int  24 69 116 162 205 253 302 351 402 454 ...
  ..$ : int  1 48 94 140 184 232 281 330 380 432 ...

[I've cut a bit this output]

 - attr(*, "group_sizes")= int  29 29 2 16 29 1 29 29 29 29 ...
 - attr(*, "biggest_group_size")= int 29
 - attr(*, "labels")='data.frame':  63 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ NetworkTrackingPixelId: int  8799 2615 8854 8869 4786 7007 3947 9109 9126 9137 ...
  ..- attr(*, "vars")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : symbol NetworkTrackingPixelId
```

Comment: I wonder if your problem can't be solved using facetting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since I don't have your dataset, I will use the `mtcars` dataset to illustrate how to do this using `dplyr` and `data.table`. Both packages are the finest examples of the `split-apply-combine` paradigm in rstats. Let me explain:

**Step 1 Split data by gear**

- `dplyr` uses the function `group_by`
- `data.table` uses argument `by`

**Step 2: Apply a function**

- `dplyr` uses `do` to which you can pass a function that uses the pieces x.
- `data.table` interprets the variables to the function in context of each piece.

**Step 3: Combine**

There is no combine step here, since we are saving the charts created to file.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %.%
  group_by(gear) %.%
  do(function(x){ggsave(
    filename = sprintf("gear_%s.pdf", unique(x$gear)), qplot(wt, mpg, data = x)
  )})

library(data.table)
mtcars_dt = data.table(mtcars)
mtcars_dt[,ggsave(
  filename = sprintf("gear_%s.pdf", unique(gear)), qplot(wt, mpg)),
  by = gear
]
```

**UPDATE:** To save all files into one pdf, here is a quick solution.

```
plots = mtcars %.%
  group_by(gear) %.%
  do(function(x) {
    qplot(wt, mpg, data = x)
  })

pdf('all.pdf')
invisible(lapply(plots, print))
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks Ramnath! that was really useful. I'm trying to save all the graphs within an unique .pdf file. I've tried to use the following function: data %.%
  group_by(NetworkTrackingPixelId) %.%
  do(function(x) {
    pdf(file = "C:\\Users\\gianluca.rossi\\Dropbox\\Data Analysis\\figure.pdf")
    ggplot(x, aes(x = Date, y = Impressions)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
    dev.off()
    }
  )
but unfortunately it returns an empty .pdf file.

Comment: That won't work. See my updated solution. The trouble is that inside the `do` loop, you are still dealing with only one piece of the data.

Comment: Absolutely loving this answer. However, what if I want to arrange my plots using e.g. arrangeGrob. mult_plot <- arrangeGrob(plots) throws the error that "input must be grobs". mult_plot <- lapply(plots, "[[", 1) gives the same error. Only mult_plot <- arrangeGrob(plots[[1]], plots[[2]], etc) works.

Comment: Do `print(do.call(arrangeGrob, plots))`.

Comment: The `dplyr` example currently abends complaining `Results 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... must be data frames, not function`. I believe you need to wrap the function as follows `(function(x){<code-here>})(.)`.  Hope that helps someone

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a project that required producing a lot of individual pngs for each record. I found I got a huge speed up doing some pretty simple parallelization. I am not sure if this is more performant than the `dplyr` or `data.table` technique but it may be worth trying. I saw a huge speed bump:

```
require(foreach)
require(doParallel)
workers <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(workers) 
foreach(i = seq(1, length(mtcars$gear)), .packages=c('ggplot2')) %dopar% {
  j <- qplot(wt, mpg, data = mtcars[i,])
  png(file=paste(getwd(), '/images/',mtcars[i, c('gear')],'.png', sep=''))
  print(j)
  dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off writing a function for plotting, then using lapply for every Network Tracking Pixel.

For example, your function might look like:

```
plot.function <- function(ntpid){
  sub = subset(dataset, dataset$networktrackingpixelid == ntpid)
  ggobj = ggplot(data=sub, aes(...)) + geom...
  ggsave(filename=sprintf("%s.pdf", ntpid))
}
```

It would be helpful for you to put a reproducible example, but I hope this works! Not sure about the vector issue though..

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, generating plots by a subsetting variable is very simple. You can use `split(...)` to split the original data into a list of data frames by `NetworkTrackingPixelId`, and then pass those to `ggplot` using `lapply(...)`. Most of the code below is just to crate a sample dataset.

```
# create sample data
set.seed(1)
names <- c("Rubicon","Google","OpenX","AppNexus","Pubmatic")
dates <- as.Date("2014-02-16")+1:10
df <- data.frame(NetworkTrackingPixelId=rep(1:5,each=10),
                 Name=sample(names,50,replace=T),
                 Date=dates,
                 Impressions=sample(1000:10000,50))
# end create sample data

pdf("plots.pdf")
lapply(split(df,df$NetworkTrackingPixelId),
       function(gg) ggplot(gg,aes(x = Date, y = Impressions)) + 
          geom_point() + geom_line()+
          ggtitle(paste("NetworkTrackingPixelId:",gg$NetworkTrackingPixelId)))
dev.off()
```

This generates a pdf containing 5 plots, one for each `NetworkTrackingPixelId`.